# Amplitude Analytics Dashboard REST API Event object

Tags: amplitude-analytics

Using the Amplitude Dashboard REST API, I am attempting to get a count of all unique times a [custom event](https://amplitude.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205469748-Dashboard-Rest-API-Export-Amplitude-Dashboard-Data#e) was triggered with a filter of a custom event property. However I am unable to even get the simplest [event segmentation](https://amplitude.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205469748-Dashboard-Rest-API-Export-Amplitude-Dashboard-Data#event-segmentation) to run, though all other endpoint hits (except [Funnels](https://amplitude.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205469748-Dashboard-Rest-API-Export-Amplitude-Dashboard-Data#funnels) which also use the `e` event parameter) are working as expected. In other words, my auth is working and I'm able to successfully get data from all the endpoints that don't require the `e` event parameter.

Here is an example of a constructed endpoint using event segmentation that is as simple as I believe it could possible be and which is 
*failing* with a 400 error.

`https://amplitude.com/api/2/events/segmentation?e=\{"event_type":"_active"\}&start=20170401&end=20170402`

While the call I want to do is ultimately more complex and involves a filter, I'm unable to just get this call which is one of the simplest event segmentation calls possible, considering the `e`, `start`, and `end` parameters are all required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try properly percent escaping the `e` parameter.

`https://amplitude.com/api/2/events/segmentation?e=%7B%22event_type%22%3A%22_active%22%7D&start=20170401&end=20170402`

Comment: I was not using curl but Java HttpClient so I needed to escape the characters like you said here. I also had spaces in my `event_type` field because my event had spaces in it. When I use UTF-8 encoding it replaces those spaces with `+` but I need them to be `%20` so I have to go in and replace them, otherwise the call also fails. But sadly that's a little brittle.

`encodedEventParameter = URLEncoder.encode(eventParameter, "UTF-8"); encodedEventParameter = encodedEventParameter.replace("+", "%20");`